# Typing in MySQL Password Through Shell Script

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell, command-line

So I'm trying to run the following lines as a shell script

```
mysql -u root -p -h myserver
connect testdb
SELECT * FROM testtable
```

However, after I type the initial "mysql -u root -p" it asks for a password rather than running the entire thing automatically. My question is, is there some line I can add to my shell script to automatically type the password in and press "Enter".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below line

```
echo "SELECT * FROM testtable" | mysql -h myserver -u root -pPASSWORD  testdb
```

replace PASSWORD with your mysql password.

Comment: @mewkie: To improve security, use a tool such as: [4.6.7 mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Comment: How would I modify this to run a .sql file? For instance something like echo mysql -h myserver -u root -pPASSWORD testdb > C:\myscript.sql

Comment: Like there's a file I want to run that usually runs as SOURCE C:\myscript.sql but when I execute it using the above method it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use  mysql -h myserver -u root -pPASSWORD testdb < myscript.sql